# SharePoint 2013 - Sorting Search Results not working (KeywordQuery-SortList)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, keywordquery

I am using **KeywordQuery** to search and the **SortList** does not affect search result, it always returns first 5 results. Any suggestions?
The code is bellow...

```
using (KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(site))
{
    var fedManager = new FederationManager(application);
    var owner = new SearchObjectOwner(SearchObjectLevel.SPSite, site.RootWeb);

    query.SourceId = fedManager.GetSourceByName("NewsRS", owner).Id;
    query.QueryText = string.Format("WorkflowStatusOWSCHCS:Approved PublishedUntilDate>=\"{0}\" OR NewsNewsPublishedDate<=\"{0}\"", DateTime.Now);
    query.KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords;
    query.RowLimit = 5;
    query.StartRow = 1;
    query.SelectProperties.Add("NewsFriendlyUrl");
    query.SelectProperties.Add("NewsNewsTeaser");
    query.SelectProperties.Add("NewsNewsDate");
    query.SelectProperties.Add("NewsPublishedUntilDate");
    query.SelectProperties.Add("NewsNewsContent");
    query.SelectProperties.Add("NewsNewsPublishedDate");
    query.SelectProperties.Add("NewsNewsImage");
    query.SortList.Add("NewsNewsDate", SortDirection.Descending);
    var searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
    var myResults = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(query);
}
```

Comment: Is NewsNewsDate flagged as Sortable?

Comment: yes it is already there, I checked that already  :-(

Comment: Have you run a full crawl on the associated content source? Have you tested sorting on an out of the box web part to ensure that everything is wired up correctly? Is date specified as a DATE type in the Managed Property?

Comment: We've checked everything, Managed Properties, mapping, nothing worked both in our environtments and in test environtment, so we decided to migrate all the queries to REST. After two days developing and testing, it is now working properly ;)

Comment: Have you checked "Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison", as suggested in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154188/sharepoint-keywordquery-how-to-sort)?

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the `query.StartRow = 1;` which will always gives you the first 5 records. Remove this option and check the search results.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the `query.RowLimit=5` in your code. You limit it to give you JUST 5 results.

Comment: He wants 5 result, but the first 5 sorted by NewsNewsDate and not ListItemId

Comment: oh, then before adding property to sortlist clear the sortlist.

Answer (score -1):

Check if field `NewsNewsDate` is `sortable = active` in search properties schema.

After apply the configuration you need to run the full crawl.